# About pytorch learning rate scheduler

Tags: python, pytorch

here is my code

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=5, gamma=0.5)

for i in range(15):
    lr = scheduler.get_lr()[0]
    lr1 = optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"]
    print(i, lr, lr1)
    scheduler.step()
```

And here is the result

```
0 0.1 0.1
1 0.1 0.1
2 0.1 0.1
3 0.1 0.1
4 0.1 0.1
5 0.025 0.05
6 0.05 0.05
7 0.05 0.05
8 0.05 0.05
9 0.05 0.05
10 0.0125 0.025
11 0.025 0.025
12 0.025 0.025
13 0.025 0.025
14 0.025 0.025
```

We can see that the when `scheduler.step()` is applied, the learning rate first decreases 0.25 times, then bounces back to 0.5 times. Is it the problem of `scheduler.get_lr()` lr or the problem of `scheduler.step()`

About the envirioment

- python=3.6.9
- pytorch=1.1.0

In addition, I can't find this problem when pytorch=0.4.1 is used.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the "problem" is in the use of `get_lr()`. To get the current LR, what you need is actually the `get_last_lr()`.

---

If you take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fde94e75568b527b424b108c272793e096e8e471/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py#L344-L352):

```py
def get_lr(self):
    if not self._get_lr_called_within_step:
        warnings.warn("To get the last learning rate computed by the scheduler, "
                      "please use `get_last_lr()`.", UserWarning)

    if (self.last_epoch == 0) or (self.last_epoch % self.step_size != 0):
        return [group['lr'] for group in self.optimizer.param_groups]
    return [group['lr'] * self.gamma
            for group in self.optimizer.param_groups]
```

When it is in the step=5, it does not satisfy the conditions (because `step_size=5`), and it will return the `lr * gamma`. <strike>The awkward thing is that you should be getting a warning when you call `get_lr()` out the the `step()` function (as you can see in the implementation above) and apparently you didn't.</strike> The warning was added only 3 months ago, so you won't have it on v1.1.0.

For the sake of completeness, what the `step()` method does is that it adds 1 to the `last_epoch` and updates the LR by calling the `get_lr()` function (see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fde94e75568b527b424b108c272793e096e8e471/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py#L141-L142)):

```py
self.last_epoch += 1
values = self.get_lr()
```

Comment: The implementation you referenced is for the latest pytorch version 1.3.1, not 1.1.0. So that's probably why Vincent_Ho doesn't get warning message. Also in his version there is no method get_last_lr().

Comment: @AndreasK. oh, yeah; there is also that :) I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!